# AngularJS $http and how to get error response

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I see the following example for calling a server-side resource:

```
UserSession.prototype.$save = function() {
    return $http.post('/users/sign_in', {
      "user" : { 
        "email" : this.email,
        "password" : this.password,
        "remember_me" : this.remember_me ? 1 : 0 
      }   
    }); 
  };
```

My question is, is it possible to see the actual error response in this code in the event the call fails? How would the above get written for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed the callbacks

```
UserSession.prototype.$save = function() {
    return $http.post('/users/sign_in', {
      "user" : { 
        "email" : this.email,
        "password" : this.password,
        "remember_me" : this.remember_me ? 1 : 0 
      }   
    })
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
       // success logic here
    })
    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
       // error logic here
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `.error()` callback [Reference](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http)

```
   UserSession.prototype.$save = function() {
        return $http.post('/users/sign_in', {
          "user" : { 
            "email" : this.email,
            "password" : this.password,
            "remember_me" : this.remember_me ? 1 : 0 
          }   
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
        });
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define the `.success` and `.error` callbacks in that function like the other answers suggest, but I feel it is more likely you would want the application code that is calling the `.$save` to determine what gets done on success or fail.

So you would leave the `.$save` function as is, and everywhere in your application you call `myUserSession.$save()`, you can just do:

```
myUserSession.$save()
   .success(function(data, httpStatus, header, config) {
       ...
   })
   .error(function(data, httpStatus, header, config) {
       ...
   });
```

Doing this just makes the code a little bit more reusable. Of course if you know for a fact on save you want the exact same behaviour everywhere, then just go with what the other answers suggest.